# Fog efect in LWJGL doesn't work

Tags: game-engine, lwjgl

I am  tring to include a fog efect into my game, but  it seems i do something worng, and i don't understand what. My fog only works if i look in only one direction and also if i look at the ground.

Here is my code snipet for Fog initialization:

```
//...

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gluPerspective(EngineConstants.fov, (float) Display.getWidth()/(float) Display.getHeight(), EngineConstants.zNear, EngineConstants.zFar);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glEnable(GL_FOG);
{
    FloatBuffer fogColor = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
    fogColor.put(0.5f).put(0.5f).put(0.5f).put(1.0f).flip();

    int fogMode = GL_EXP;
    glFogi(GL_FOG_MODE, fogMode);
    glFog(GL_FOG_COLOR, fogColor);
    glFogf(GL_FOG_DENSITY, 0.35f);
    glHint(GL_FOG_HINT, GL_DONT_CARE);
    glFogf(GL_FOG_START, 3.0f);
    glFogf(GL_FOG_END, 6.0f);
 }

 glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

//...
```

after runing this code snipet i obtain this efect

[image]

, but if i rotate slightly to the right or to the left i optain this (not desired)

[image]

i've been stugling whit this for a week now , if someone has an idea of what is wrong whit it please leave a coment or an aswer.

Here is how i build my flore

```
glNewList(floorDisplayList, GL_COMPILE);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex3f(-WorldConstants.gridSize, WorldConstants.floreHeight, -WorldConstants.gridSize);
            glTexCoord2f(0, WorldConstants.gridSize * 10 * WorldConstants.titleSize);
            glVertex3f(-WorldConstants.gridSize, WorldConstants.floreHeight, WorldConstants.gridSize);
            glTexCoord2f(WorldConstants.gridSize * 10 * WorldConstants.titleSize, WorldConstants.gridSize * 10 * WorldConstants.titleSize);
            glVertex3f(WorldConstants.gridSize, WorldConstants.floreHeight, WorldConstants.gridSize);
            glTexCoord2f(WorldConstants.gridSize * 10 * WorldConstants.titleSize, 0);
            glVertex3f(WorldConstants.gridSize, WorldConstants.floreHeight, -WorldConstants.gridSize);
        glEnd();
glEndList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many days of thinking (try and error), i've finily figured out , I will post my answer here maybe it will help others.

On my code above i've tried to implement a fog system on veri larger piece of land, this land is actuali a single entity so lwjgl will automaticle fog the entire block .